# Can't get image orientation neither with EXIF nor from MediaStore

Tags: android, bitmap, exif

This is the details of one sample picture I try to get orientation of:
[image: image with orientation 270]

Using EXIF I always get ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED (=0). Here is the code:

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imageUri.getPath());
int rotation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);
```

So, I searched and found bunch of similar questions. The suggestions were using the details of image in MediaStore. I do it like this:

```
String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION};
try {
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(imageUri, projection, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        orientation = cursor.getInt(0);
    }
    cursor.close();
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

The above code doesn't also give any result as, "cursor" becomes null!

Having the orientation I will do image rotation and stuff. What should I do to get a photo orientation?

Answer (score 3):

Your first piece of code will only work if `imageUri` has a `file` scheme. Many times, it will not.

Your second piece of code will only work if `imageUri` is a `Uri` from `MediaStore`.

Instead, use [an `ExifInterface` implementation that works with streams](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/05/31/tale-two-exifinterfaces.html), so you can use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get the orientation. This should work for all `Uri` values, though whether or not the JPEG contains an orientation header will vary by the image.

[This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/EXIFRotater) demonstrates the approach. In my case, the images are in `assets/`, and so my `InputStream` comes from `AssetManager`, not `ContentResolver`, but otherwise it should work the same:

```
 ExifInterface exif=new ExifInterface();

 exif.readExif(is, ExifInterface.Options.OPTION_ALL);

 ExifTag tag=exif.getTag(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
 int orientation=(tag==null ? -1 : tag.getValueAsInt(-1));
```

(where `is` is the `InputStream`)

Comment: Is it possible to have a photo which has an orientation value shown in image details page of android gallery, and we can't get that value programmatically? Cause that's what happens with me using your code. I can get the orientation of image A and no problem. But then image B is right beside it in the same folder, and has the same orientation, but the variable 'tag' becomes null !

Comment: @EmJiHash: If the orientation is not coming from the EXIF header, I do not know where your gallery app is coming up with an orientation, other than via some hard-coded default.